# NOAA weather broadcasts

Tags: reception

I am getting no NOAA weather broadcasts, after loading all NOAA weather channels into memory or entering the frequencies manually on a new Baofeng UV-5R?? Why? Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Hi Rich, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking the correct frequencies (162.400 MHz, 162.425 MHz, 162.450 MHz, 162.475 MHz, 162.500 MHz, 162.525 MHz, 162.550 MHz), have all settings properly set (ex. volume control), and have a decent antenna installed and can't hear anything, then the NOAA signal entering your radio is simply too weak.
Try holding the MONI button for each frequency to bypass the squelch to see if you can make out any faint reception. Use a good grip on the radio while holding it upright (antenna pointing up) or try a few different orientations. Try it outside and try it in different locations. Compare it with another weather radio to find out if there is really no signal or perhaps something wrong with the Baofeng radio. Also look at the NOAA transmitter and coverage map to see which direction the closest transmitter is from and if something might be blocking the path such as a hill.
https://www.weather.gov/nwr/Maps